# Public Access Problem in Gen App Builder Integration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, vertex-ai-search

I needed a model that can be trained using PDFs. Therefore, I am creating an app with unstructured data using the Gen App Builder by utilizing the search engine. In the integration part, I retrieve the generated "code to your web application" HTML and store it to Cloud Storage. Then I make it public by setting the access through Cloud Storage.

In the app of Gen App Builder integration section, I select 'public' for the authorization type and choose the domain 'storage.googleapis.com'. However, when I open the link in incognito mode, I receive the message 'Problem loading results, please try again'. Upon examining the details, I see the error 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401'. How can I resolve this situation?

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .grecaptcha-badge {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    </style>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

    <script src="https://cloud.google.com/ai/gen-app-builder/client"></script>
    <gen-search-widget
      configId="xxx"
      triggerId="searchWidgetTrigger">
    </gen-search-widget>
    <input placeholder="Search here" id="searchWidgetTrigger" />

</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try to clear the browser’s cache and cookies for a possible solution. If that fails, try flushing your DNS cache ? and Check authentication credentials make sure you’ve entered the valid username and password. If the issue persists, try resetting the password.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this behavior for a short time right after creating the site on Google Cloud Storage and adding the `storage.googleapis.com` domain to the public access domain list.

https://cloud.google.com/generative-ai-app-builder/docs/add-widget

However, it resolved itself after about a half hour and I was able to use the widget on a Cloud Storage static site. It does take some time for the domain allowlisting for public access to take effect. Has this issue been persisting?

Comment: The problem is no longer persisting. Thank you for your help.